# Mongo data of localhost app on laptop not showing on cell phone on same network

Tags: android, mongodb, server, localhost

I want to view an app that is running on my laptop at localhost:8080 on an Android cell phone. The app is using local MongoDB, which works fine on the laptop for all CRUD operations.

By directing the browser on my Android via `http://<ip4 address of laptop>:8080` I can see the UI. However, none of my Mongo data appears.

If anyone can tell me how to get this working or if it is even possible to do I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

On Mongodb you must configure IpBinding to access from "outside":
[IP Binding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/)

But I think the app is running on your local machine and you want to see only the app.

Check if the port 8080 is open on your system and firewall.